# Does the order of if else matter for performance? e.g. put the most likely condition in the front is better

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jit

I'm trying to measure if the order of `if else` affects performance.

For example, if

```java
if (condition == more likely condition) {}
else /** condition == rare condition **/ {}
```

is faster than

```java
if (condition == rare condition) {}
else /** condition == more likely condition **/ {}
```

I think maybe JIT should be able to optimise it no matter which order I put it? Couldn't find any documentation on this though.

I tried to test it out myself with following benchmark. Based on it, I don't see strong evidence that the order matters. Because if it does, I think the throughput when `bias=0.9` (probability of `if (zeroOrOne == 1)` is true is 0.9) should be higher than when `bias=0.1` (`else` probability is 0.9).

```java
public class BranchBench {
    @Param({ "0.02", "0.1", "0.9", "0.98", })
    private double bias;

    @Param("10000")
    private int count;

    private final List<Byte> randomZeroOnes = new ArrayList<>(count);

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        Random r = new Random(12345);

        for (int c = 0; c < count; c++) {
            byte zeroOrOne = (byte) (c < (bias * count) ? 1 : 0);
            randomZeroOnes.add(zeroOrOne);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(randomZeroOnes, r);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int static_ID_ifElse() {
        int i = 0;
        for (final Byte zeroOrOne : randomZeroOnes) {
            if (zeroOrOne == 1) {
                i++;
            } else {
                i--;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

```
Benchmark                     (bias)  (count)   Mode  Cnt    Score   Error   Units
BranchBench.static_ID_ifElse    0.02    10000  thrpt   15  137.409 ± 1.376  ops/ms
BranchBench.static_ID_ifElse     0.1    10000  thrpt   15  129.277 ± 1.552  ops/ms
BranchBench.static_ID_ifElse     0.9    10000  thrpt   15  125.640 ± 5.858  ops/ms
BranchBench.static_ID_ifElse    0.98    10000  thrpt   15  137.427 ± 2.396  ops/ms
```

Comment: I don't think this is a real question, but more an entire research project ;)
A far as I know in Java code is only compiled once, so the order may be relevant as Java hasn't any runtime knowledge like "more likely condition".
Eventually the case is too simple to be discussed like this. There are probably much more parameters, like threading... which has more effect than the order here ;)

Comment: @Adrian `in Java code is only compiled once` <- I think that's right. But that's why I'm saying `JIT` might be able to optimise it

Comment: That’s wrong. In case of the commonly used Hotspot JVM, the JIT compiler will start its work after the code has been executed by the interpreter a few times, so likelihoods are available. Further, the JVM has multiple compilers with different optimization strategies, so code may get compiled more than once. You should add a test with 0.5 (and perhaps even more steps within), as the slight differences in the results seem to show a trend, i.e. that a higher likelihood of one case yields a higher throughput regardless of which case it is.

Comment: thanks @Holger. I did add tests with 0.5 and it's true that "higher likelihood of one case yields a higher throughput" (supposedly because of 0.5 yields the worst branch prediction). I didn't include the result here as I thought the 4 bias here are enough to make my point.

Comment: Of course, you can implement your specific example branch free, `for(int zeroOrOne: randomZeroOnes) i += (zeroOrOne - 1) | 1;` which does not depend on the actual likelihood (and will be faster in most cases).

Comment: How do you know which condition is more likely to be true? The performance will be faster if the first condition that is checked is met, because then the code will not have to proceed to the next condition. However, the performance difference for a single if-else conditional check will almost certainly be negligible. This isn't a matter of the compiler being efficient, but a matter of how you write your code based on the workflow the program will follow during normal use. If someone follows the more rare condition, the code will be slower if that condition is checked for second, naturally.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

On modern processors I don't think the order of your conditionals really matter that much anymore. As part of the instruction pipeline, processors will do what is called *branch prediction*; where it guesses which condition will be true and pre-loads the instructions into the pipeline.

These days, processors guess correctly >90% of the time, so any hand-written conditional tweaking is less important.

There are quite a lot of literature on branch prediction:

https://dzone.com/articles/branch-prediction-in-java

https://www.baeldung.com/java-branch-prediction

Comment: `processors guess correctly >90% of the time` - I suppose so long as it's not 100%, it's still recommended to do hand-written conditional tweaking

Comment: This is only true when the number of conditions to check is small, and the cost of each one is really really cheap. If the rare condition to check involves complex computation, then checking it later than a common case will be faster overall.

Comment: @boneill the question’s title may be misleading, the actual question is not referring to the order of multiple conditions but only whether to test for one condition or its negation.